# Efficient way to calculate geographic density in Pandas?

Tags: python, performance, loops, pandas, geolocation

I have a large list of longitude and latidue data corresponding to fast food places in the U.S. For each fast food place, I want to know how many other fast food places are within 5 miles. I could calculate this in Pandas using Geopy like so (each row in the DataFrame is a different fast food place):

```
import pandas as pd
import geopy.distance

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fast Food Place':[1,2,3], 'Lat':[33,34,35], 'Lon':[42,43,44]})

for index1, row1 in df.iterrows():
    num_fastfood = 0

    for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
        # calculate distance in miles between longitude and latitude
        dist = geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(row1[['Lat','Lon']],
                                               row2[['Lat','Lon']]).miles

        # if fast food is within 5 miles, increment num_fastfood
        if dist < 5: # if less than five miles
            num_fastfood = num_fastfood + 1

    df.loc[index1, 'num_fastfood_5miles'] = num_fastfood - 1 # (subtract 1 to exclude self)
```

But this is extremely slow on very large data sets (i.e. 50,000 rows). I considered using a KDTree for the search, but curious if other people have a much quicker method?

Comment: KDTrees are hard to beat in this task. Any particular reason **not** to use one?

Comment: @Paul not in particular - more curiosity. And it will take me a quick second to remember how to use sklearn's KDTree setup. Something like `tree = KDTree(my_lat_long)

# Query all the values
nnDist, nnIdx = tree.query(my_lat_long)` and then cycle through nnDist?

Comment: Nah, use `query_ball_tree` to get all points within a radius: `tree = KDTree(my_lat_long); within_5 = tree.query_ball_tree(tree, radius=5)`. Then flatten the nested list and count.

Comment: @Paul didn't realize that existed, thanks. If I do it this way, it's looking solely at lat-long, but I need to incorporate geopy to get 'true' distance in miles from it

Comment: Just precompute what 5 miles amounts to in degrees, then use lat/long.

Comment: @Paul Good point - looks to be about 0.0724 degrees. That's accurate enough for me. I think its `query_radius` in SKLearn now, I don't see a `query_ball_tree`. Thank you for the help. If you put an answer in I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementation with `scipy.spatial.cKDTree`:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

def find_neighbours_within_radius(xy, radius):
    tree = cKDTree(xy)
    within_radius = tree.query_ball_tree(tree, r=radius)
    return within_radius

def flatten_nested_list(nested_list):
    return [item for sublist in nested_list for item in sublist]

def total_neighbours_within_radius(xy, radius):
    neighbours = find_neighbours_within_radius(xy, radius)
    return len(flatten_nested_list(neighbours))
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `TypeError: query_ball_tree() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)` with this UPDATE: Nevermind, I see I have to provide it with lat/lon distance separately

Comment: Sorry, the keyword is `r`, not radius for `cKDTree.query_ball_tree`. Fixed the code.